# Freeform subobject in json-schema

Tags: openapi, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I am drafting an API documentation with swagger.io and is trying to make it fit to our use case. The system is going to receive and process data from all sources, and they would each have different sets of fields.

While the product of the processing share the same schema, we want to include the input in the schema too for reference purpose. For instance, given

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
    "bar": "baz"
}
```

The product of the processing is

```
{
    "original": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "bar": "baz"
    }
    "processed": {
        "stdFieldA": "bar",
        "stdFieldB": "baz"
    }
}
```

Assuming for each input from different sources, we end up having `stdFieldA` and `stdFieldB`. So the response schema object we have

```
type: object
properties:
    processed:
        type: object
        properties:
            stdFieldA:
                type: string
            stdFieldB:
                type: string
```

now that we have the `processed` subobject defined, can we define a freeform object for the original input, so that this object coming from another source is valid

```
{
    "alpha": "lorem",
    "beta": "ipsum"
}
```

If I don't get any answer to this, my workaround to the problem would be storing the original input as string (convert the original input into JSON string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type: object` without `properties` describes a free-form object. So the response schema can be:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
    original:
        type: object    # <----------
    processed:
        type: object
        properties:
            stdFieldA:
                type: string
            stdFieldB:
                type: string
```

Comment: could you specify the possible types of the values of the objects? For example, restrict the types of the values to just "strings"?

Comment: @exhuma yes, see [Dictionaries / Hashmaps](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/).

Comment: @Helen your linked is sadly blocked by corporate policy -- is there another source?

Comment: @KimTaylor try the Internet Archive copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20230915233518/https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/

Comment: @Helen Thanks for that but also blocked :-(
The unintended consequences of "corporate policy" do force me to stay very creative at times.

I solved my issue using patternProperties for free-form objects after finding additionalProperties did not respect further contraints on its subobjects.