# How do i document optional RESTful JSON API attributes?

Tags: json, rest, swagger, api-design

I've been trying to figure out how to design the documentation for an API I'm building. I've been using Swagger (swagger.io) along with JSONSchema to help me structure the documentation, but I've run into a snag. Some of our object will have lots of what we call "metadata" attached to them, which is basically an arbitrary and variable dictionary of key/values. For example:

```
{
  "id": "aabbbccdd",
  "name": "Object 1",
  "metadata": {
    "attributeA": "This is a text attribute",
    "attributeB": {
        "key1": "complex attribute",
        "key2": "complex attribute 2",
    },
    "attributeC": 1234
  }
},
{
  "id": "eeffffggghh",
  "name": "Object 2",
  "metadata": {
    "attributeA": "This is a text attribute with a different value",
    "attributeD": "Another text attribute",
    "attributeE": True
  }
}
```

So I could document the object representation by enumerating *all* the metadata attributes, but the list is long and will likely vary over time.

Is there another way to approach documenting this, or designing the API in a different way?

Comment: What is the metadata for? Why is it arbitrary and variable? Sounds like you could document all the metadata once and link to that doc from every object that has metadata.

Comment: We deploy our app for different customers and the metadata are configured differently for each deployment.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [free-form object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41606152/113116) schema.