# Python Flask/Connexion with Swagger, name of nested JSON-style object only known at runtime

Tags: python, json, flask, swagger, connexion

I am working on a web server with flask/connexion and i am configuring it via a *swagger.yml* file. I am not allowed to show the original file but I want to do something like this in the parameters section for a post operation:

```
- name: someparam
  ...
  schema:
      type: object
      properties:
          someprop:
              type: object
              properties:
                  my_nested_object:
                      ...
```

The problem is the following: *someprop* is a java script object which should be saved in a json file and the key/name of *my_nested_object* is only known at runtime because *someprop* will contain more than one object of its "type". Hence the key identifies the object.

**Edit:** I just realized that also the count of nested objects is a problem since I don't know it at runtime either. Is there really no way to define "dynamic" objects in my swagger config?

Is there any (alternative) way to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger dictionary parameter definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867499/113116)

Comment: This should solve my problem. How exactly would I use that in my context?

Comment: If `someprop` is a string-to-object map you would define it as `type: object` + `additionalProperties: {type: object}`. If it's string-to-anything map, then just `type: object` (i.e. a [free-form object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41606152/113116)).

Comment: alright, thanks. I specified `{additionalProperties: true}` (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/). Don't know if it is really required since you left it out but it should basically mean that it can map to anything.