# Define OpenAPI 2.0 returning JSON object of unknown type

Tags: openapi

I want to describe OpenAPI that returns JSON object of unknown/any type.

If I define return type in the yaml below I still see generated client returning just a raw string.

```
responses:
  200:
    description: Returns any JSON object
    schema:
      type: string
      format: object
```

Is there a way to describe the return type as a JSON object without describing its schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free-form subobject in JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41606152/113116)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An arbitrary object is defined as `type: object`, so the correct definition is:

```yaml
responses:
  200:
    description: Returns any JSON object
    schema:
      type: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Helen's answer you can also explicitly define the content type besides the actual payload being unknown. This is for OpenAPI 3.0.

```yaml
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  type: object
```

[See a full example here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/api/explorer/).

Comment: Thanks! I also had to make sure that in the response headers set `headers.set("content-type", "application/json");`